# Implement an API to use HTTP extensions like CalDAV

Tags: 9

I want to create a calDAV API endpoint. The client would contact my API using methods mentioned in the sabre DAV client documentation https://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/ (sabre dav seems to be used by alot of projects so I am using it as a protocol documentation).

Now I am completely lost how to implement that in Drupal. There was a webDAV module but it's abandoned for 4 years and a calDAV module that's abandoned for 9 years...

Can I use REST API and hook it to respond to HTTP request methods like PROPFIND?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share some code? Have you experimented with issuing a PROPFIND request to your site?

Comment: I have tried to enable REST API core plugins (all of them including UI) and I tried to allow all methods in  the default.services.yml (setting the empty brackets there to ['*']). I use RESTer (Firefox) and POSTman (Chrome) to send any methods (not only PROPFIND), but always get "405 Method not allowed" error. I made a test REST view using GET which works as expected, but all methods not listed in REST API documentation fail with 405.

Comment: PS: I also tried to write an own controller, just a test. Made a route to the controller and the Route works with GET (in normal browser and in RESTer plugin). I found a symfony question that suggested adding /** *@Method({"DELETE"}) */ to the controller and I tried to access my controller route in RESTer with this method, but still got 405. Seems the request doesn't even get through to my controller when I use a non-standard method.

Comment: After looking into it, I think that the PROPFIND method will be a continual problem since it is no longer supported and is not universally recognized. From what I understand, the purpose of PROPFIND is to return data in a XML format. it might be best to use standard GET request and respond with XML-formatted data.

Comment: The problem is, that DAV clients like DAVx5 use PROPFIND to "Query capabilities with HTTP" - see: https://www.davx5.com/manual/technical_information.html#synchronization I need to find a way to respond to PROPFIND with XML containing calendar data for the user. I could use a twig for the controller to fill in the data from the db into a proper xml template, but if PROPFIND would not get through to my controller, I have no chance doing so. I also would have to implement the other methods WebDAV uses to extend HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this.
I added method to the route and @Method({'PROPFIND'}) to the source (I am not sure if this is needed for Symfony).

```
class DavController extends ControllerBase {

/**     
 * @Method({"PROPFIND"})       
 */
 public function dav() {
     //Get the data, fill into xml twig

        $response = new Response();
        $xml = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($build);
        $response->setContent($xml);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');

        return $response
 }
```

module_name.routing.yml (this seems to be mandatory):

```
    entity.dav_controller.dav:
        path: 'path/to/dav/enpoint'
        methods: [PROPFIND]
        defaults:
            _controller: '\Drupal\path\to\DavController::dav'
            _title: 'my_title'
        requirements: 
            _permission: 'access content'
```

This works in 8 and 9.

Note that this does not involve the Drupal REST API. This is supposed to be an own implementation and won't solve the issue for anyone who wants to use REST API to answer to such methods. I am not experienced enough with Drupal to explain if and how one could configure REST API to accept HTTP methods not listed in the REST API documentation. Maybe one could extend own controllers from the REST API, but I didn't inquire into how to do that.